# Prepared statement with quotes in query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was writing a prepared statement and for the table name I passed user obtained variable string.

So this works,

`String m_table_variable = "blah";` // get from request object

`PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from "+m_table_variable+"");`

While this does not,

`PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from '+m_table_variable+'")`

What triviality am I missing here?

Comment: Euh...no, that won't compile.

Comment: It compiles fine I have cross checked.

Comment: Then you aren't showing what you are actually compiling.

Comment: I am sorry I will include more details. and some corrections.

Answer (score 1):

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from " +m_table_variable)
```

try this

of course if the `m_table_variable` is a String with name of a table

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is quite straight forward, the first example concatenates three Strings namely `"select * from "`, `"blah"` and `""` together.

The second example uses one String which literally is `"select * from '+m_table_variable+'"` and the variable is not concatenated to the final String. Personally I wouldn't dynamically allow the table name to be injected into the SQL statement, read up on SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Your first one will not even compile, you need to use \" to insert a quote into a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `"` from String using `\`, otherwise it will not compile.

```
PreparedStatement ps 
        = conn.prepareStatement("select * from \"m_table_variable\"");
```